# POST privatekey to reCAPTCHA API

Tags: ajax, security, recaptcha

I am implementing the [reCAPTCHA AJAX API](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#AJAX) as described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/verify.html). The documentation says that the privatekey must be POSTed to the verification URL.

Can someone explain why it is acceptable to be POSTing a private key? It seems like this would be a security issue? In fact, how is it acceptable to have the privatekey in a client side script at all?

Comment: The POST should be coming from **your server**, not the client.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I am referring to the AJAX API, where the request originates from client side javascript. Perhaps I misunderstood something though?

Comment: @nona-urbiz What AJAX API? submitting the request to reCAPTCHA directly from the client isn't safe, as you stated in your question *It seems like this would be a security issue*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST should be coming from **your server**, not the client.

- Client sends a post with the challenge & attempted answer to your server.
- Your server makes a HTTP call to reCAPTCHA with the remoteip, challenge, attempted answer and the private key.
- If the response from reCAPTCHA = true, then proceed for example submit the data to the database.
- If the response from reCAPTCHA = false, display a error message, optionally showing a new challenge.

Comment: Oh! That makes a lot more sense. I think I was confused because the doc says "To verify the solution, you will need to pass two variables from the widget (along with a few other server side parameters) to the reCAPTCHA verification API.". Thanks! For the record though, when you say "your server makes an HTTP call", that's just another POST right? or on second thought, shouldn't these all be GETs?

Comment: @nona-urbiz A server to server HTTP request using `curl` for example. The reCAPTCHA docs state they should be passed in `POST`